# nested ngFor in dropdown unable to bind data to ngModel in angular5

Tags: angular, dropdown, ngfor, ngmodel

```
class floor = {
    id: number,
    baseId: number,
    floorChild: [{
            id: number,
            name: string
        }
    ]
};
```

I have an array of floor as floors[];

I need to bind the id of each element of array floors[] with the matching id of its floorChild to display in the dropdown when the data is fetched.

***component.html***

```
<div *ngFor="let floor of floors;let i = index">
<div class="form-group" >
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <label>{{getBaseName(floor.baseId)}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="floors[i].id" name="id">

<option value="0">Unassigned</option>
<option *ngFor="let child of floors[i].floorChild" [value]="child.id"  [selected]="child.id==floors[i].id ? 'selected' : ''">{{child.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to bind the child.id with floor[i].id so that the dropdown displays tha corresponding data where the match happens.

right now it shows just unassigned (value="0") for everything in the dropdown.